# Error in R - no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "formula"

Tags: r, predict, model-fitting

I'd like to ask for help with the predict function. I want to get a fitting line to my data analog to abline(). For a different system I used this approach before.

```
mod1<-glm(data$Lengthmm ~ data$qbH.yr.med, family=quasipoisson,
    subset = data$Age==1)

xv <- seq(min(data$qbH.yr.med), max(data$qbH.yr.med), 
    length.out = length(data$Lengthmm))                #    poisson regression

yv <- predict(mod1 ~ data$qbH.yr.med, family=quasipoisson, list(x = xv))
```

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
>     no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "formula"

```
typeof(mod1)
# [1] "list"
typeof(xv)
# [1] "double"
class(mod1)
# [1] "glm" "lm" 
class(xv)
# [1] "numeric"
```

I have no idea why it asks for the "formula" as non of my factors are of this class... I would by happy about help, or ideas for this error.

Comment: You should be using your model object (`mod1`) with `predict()`, But you would also avoid using `$` in your formulas or you will likely not get the result you want. But when asking for help, be sure to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample data so we can run the code. It's unclear to me how this would have ever worked with other models. Probably check out the `?predict` help page for examples of usage.

Answer (score 2):

As others have commented, it's hard to see how this could ever have worked in the past.  There are a few points here:

- it's best practice to supply a `data` argument and use only the names of the variables (i.e. `Lengthhmm`, not `data$Lengthmm`), especially if you want `predict()` and other post-fitting machinery to work
- for `predict` you should supply the fitted model and (optionally) a `newdata` argument that matches the original data frame
- it's a good idea not to call your data `data` (this masks a built-in R function, although it doesn't *usually* cause trouble)

Making up a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(Lengthmm=1:10,qbH.yr.med=rpois(10,1),
                 Age=rep(1,10))
```

Fitting:

```
mod1 <- glm(Lengthmm ~ qbH.yr.med, family=quasipoisson,
            data=dd,
            subset = (Age==1))
xv <- with(dd,
         data.frame(qbH.yr.med=seq(min(qbH.yr.med), max(qbH.yr.med), 
                        length.out = length(Lengthmm))))
yv <- predict(mod1, newdata=xv)
```

By the way, it seems a bit fishy to use `family=quasipoisson` for a response called `Lengthmm` - I would generally think that lengths would be continuous, and hence more likely to be Normal or log-Normal (or some other transformation of Normal) rather than Poisson-distributed or distributed with a variance proportional to their mean (i.e. "quasi-Poisson" ...)

Answer (score 0):

You are predicting on `mod1 ~ data$qbH.yr.med` this is an object of class formula. You can easily identify this by noticing the `~`. In your case you want to use the model object you created, that is `mod1`